# How to merge two arrays, and remove the duplicated elements sametime with solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, solidity-0.8.x

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract BatchData {


  function getArray1() internal view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory arr = new address[](3);
    arr[0] = address(0x111);
    arr[1] = address(0x222);
    arr[2] = address(0x333);
    return arr;
  }

  function getArray2() internal view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory arr = new address[](3);
    arr[0] = address(0x111);
    arr[1] = address(0x444);
    arr[2] = address(0x555);
    return arr;
  }

  function mergeArray() public view {
    address[] memory array1 = getArray1();
    address[] memory array2 = getArray2();

    // TODO: merging logic  
  }

}
```

It is hard to merge two arrays to one and removing the duplicates. I am trying to declare a new variable to accept the merged arrays, and then use two for loop for it. While it just does not know the length of merged array, as below:

```
address[] memory newArray = new address[](<unknown here>);
```

Does someone know how to solve this? Or have a new idea to merge the arrays?
Please give a hand.